# How do you convert spaces as underscores before uploading to s3 with Carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I have a rails project where I'm using Carrierwave to upload files to Amazon s3.

I get a `bad URI(is not URI?)` error on my edit action when I upload a file with spaces in it such as `File Name.mp3`. How do I convert the spaces in a filename to underscores before uploading to s3?

Is there a configuration option I'm not finding in the docs, or do I need to create a method to do this?

**Updated:**

Here's my uploaders/track_uploader.rb: https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/5025757

Here's the model I'm attaching files to: https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/5025731

Here's my controller: https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/5025765

Note that when I use `"#{original_filename}".underscore` in the uploader the file uploads fine but it doesn't convert the filename, it just keeps the original filename with the space, like this: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s3/sh/c5a08968-6f6d-4de8-a768-830a378572bc/10ee719307f3c587b531a37868127209

And if I use `"#{filename}".underscore` I get a `stack level too deep` error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

uploaders/track_uploader.rb:

```
def filename
  "#{@original_filename}".gsub(/\s+/, '_')
end
```

Replaces any whitespace character with an underscore. Alternately, you could use `/\W+/` to match non-word characters (not a letter, number, or underscore).

Keep in mind that this method doesn't do anything but produce a string based on "@original_filename". You still have to set the filename attribute.

Have you tried the following?

```
def fix_filename
  @original_filename.gsub!(/\s+/, '_')
end
```

Comment: Thanks that got me on the right track, this ended up working https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/5025944. I had to restart the server and sidekiq for it to work though. That was throwing me off. Always check the tires, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `parameterize` method. This method will make `uri` to friendly `uri`.

For example:

```
>> "http://songs.com/my file.mp3".parameterize
=> #<ActiveSupport::Multibyte::Chars:0xef4eb5c @wrapped_string="http-songs-com-my-file-mp3">
>> "http://songs.com/my file.mp3".parameterize.to_s
=> "http-songs-com-my-file-mp3"
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just convert the url after the file has been uploaded? I'd like to convert the filename before it gets uploaded to s3. Seems like I should be able to do something like this https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/5025677, but that's not working. I'm basing that idea on this article: https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Create-random-and-unique-filenames-for-all-versioned-files

Comment: Showing the code in your original Question that reflects your efforts based on those articles would be helpful. It suggests you have more of an understanding of how Carrierwave works than one might be led to think based on your Question in it's current form (lacking any code you're using).

Comment: Added my code. I've tried using 'filename' and 'original_filename' but neither work.